SDK does not contain 'libarclite' erro on Xcode
I am on macOS 14.6 and I am using Xcode 15.4 to build an application with a graphical user interface in C++. If I build the app in Release mode, I get the error

clang: error: SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a'; try increasing the minimum deployment target

Yes, this question has been asked already, but none of the answers shown online work for me. I do not see the 'Pods' file in my app, so I cannot change the deployment target as suggested in the answers.
I also selected the target, changed the 'Minimum Deployments' but the error persists.
Any ideas?

While most references to this error seem to be related to using CocoaPods, you should still follow the basic advice in related answers and that is to ensure nothing in your project is referencing an old deployment target. Make sure everything used in your project is using a newer deployment target.
